# How to display scene statistics on start up

Tags: interface

Is there a way to have the scene statistic always appear in my viewport? I have tried to click on save preference to always show when I insert a new mesh into my viewport. When I close Blender and then reopen, I have to check it on again for it to appear.

[image]

Comment: What does it give if you go into File > Defaults > Save Startup File?

Comment: OK this worked. Never knew that feature.

Merci!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*, it will save your current settings as the default settings when you'll create a new file.